# How to align <td rowspan ="value"> value to center vertically?

Tags: html, css

I need to align `td` cell value to center, both horizontally and vertically. `<td>` has a `rowspan` attribute.

The output right now is like:

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  D 
1  |  2  |  3  |  4
1  |  2  |  3  |  
1  |  2  |  3  |
```

Desired:

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  D
1  |  2  |  3  |  
1  |  2  |  3  |  4
1  |  2  |  3  |  
1  |  2  |  3  |
```

Comment: try vertical-align:middle;

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try :

```
<td style="vertical-align : middle;text-align:center;">
```

Answer (score 2):

use `<td rowspan="4" align="center">4</td>` its work

```css
table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td rowspan="4" align="center">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Bhargav, thanks for the answer... I tried to put padding for only that one particular td with inline styling.. and it doesn't work.. why?

Comment: <td rowspan="<?= $totalRows; ?>" style="background-color: #f3f4f5; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;">5.0</td>

Comment: so add `padding:` in style easily

Comment: I tried... didn't work.. But 'vertical-align : middle;' worked... 
I don't know why 'padding:' didn't work..

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[live fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulworld/o59nyj0g/24/)

Code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            first
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            Second
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            Third
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">
            Fourth
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          fifth
        </td>
        <td>
          sixth
        </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You easily do it with css using CSS selectors and the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property.

Any `td` or `th` by default has a `rowspan = 1`.

To position the `rowspan`'d `td` text in the center, just do this:
Taking an example of `rowspan = "3"`

```
td[rowspan = "3"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you want to make it generic, just use it as below:

```
th[rowspan]:not([rowspan="1"]) {
    vertical-align : middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td rowspan="4" tyle="text-align:center;">4</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add rowspan 4.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="4">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td rowspan ="4">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The text is centered aligned by default. Please check existing css as it is overwrite the align property.

Comment: I'm using <table class="table table-striped table-hover"> . could it be hindering the default alignment?

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
<td align="center" valign="middle">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add general class into your css.

```
 .mytable td[rowspan] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `align` attribute

```
<td align="center">Name</td>
```

Comment: *align* attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

style='text-align:center';