# How to make value display vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to the framework Laravel, so I want to edit that value from class will be displayed in the blade vertically instead of horizontally

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<style>

.header {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    height: 100px;

}
h5{
    height: 50px;
}

.main {
    background-color: beige;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}




.footer {
    background-color: #bdf7f1;
    height: 80px;
}


.slideleft {
    /* position: fixed; */
    width: 200px;
    top: 100;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 80;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #f5bdf7 ;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.slideleft tbody{
    flex-direction: column-reverse;

}

.header h5{
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img width="100" src="https://png2.cleanpng.com/sh/aff73ee71947de183ecae78db06e7b76/L0KzQYm3V8A2N5NwjpH0aYP2gLBuTfNwdaF6jNd7LXnmf7B6TfNwdqVmeAY2bHn2hH76mf1jd50yTdQ8ZUm0dIa4g8gxQGgzSqcAMUa5Q4e4VcMxQGM8SqQ6MUG5SHB3jvc=/kisspng-computer-icons-contact-list-symbol-5b3e91d51c8087.2551663615308272211168.png" 
        
        
        alt="">

    </div>
    <div>
        
        <h5>Addres Book</h5>
    </div>
    
</div>
<div class="main">
   
    
    <div class="slideleft">
        <div class="upper">
            <a href="{{ route('addstudents') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="text-align: center;" >
            <button>Add New Contact</button>
            </a>
        </div>
       
        <tbody>
            @if ($students->count() >0)
                @foreach ($students as $student)
                <tr>
                    {{-- <a href=" "></a>              --}}
                    <a href="{{ route ('editstudents', ['id' => $student->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" style="padding: 1px 8px;">

                    <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>

                </a>

                </tr>
                    
                @endforeach
                
            @else
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">No students found!</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        </tbody>

    </div>



    
    <div>
    
        <div class="cotainer">
            <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h5 class="card-title">All Students</h5>
                            <a href="{{ route('addstudents') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="float:right;">Add New Student</a>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    @if (session()->has('message'))
                                    <div class="alert alert-success text-center">{{ session('message') }}</div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." wire:model="search" />
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Student ID</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                        <th>Phone</th>
                                        <th>Image</th>
                                        <th>Birth</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <img src="  " alt="">
    
                                <tbody>
                                    @if ($students->count() >0)
                                        @foreach ($students as $student)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $student->student_id }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $student->email }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $student->phone }}</td>
    
                                        
                                            <td>
                                                <img width="50" src="{{ asset('storage/' . $student->image) }} " alt="">
    
                                              
                                                
                                               </td>
                                            <td>{{ $student->birth }}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                
    
    
                                                <a href="{{ route ('editstudents', ['id' => $student->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" style="padding: 1px 8px;">Edit</a>
    
                                                
                                                 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="confirmDelete({{ $student->id }})"
                                                  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  style="padding: 1px 8px;">Delete</a>
    
    
    
    
                                                
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                            
                                        @endforeach
                                        
                                    @else
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">No students found!</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endif
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    </div>
    
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I used to do this   [How to align <td rowspan ="value"> value to center vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344183/how-to-align-td-rowspan-value-value-to-center-vertically)

that my code
from this

```
<td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
```

become this

```
 <td style="vertical-align : middle;text-align:center;">{{ $student->name }}</td>
```

but it's not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtLcz.png)

what I want is

```
add student

name1

name2

name3
```

before this, I learn HTML and CSS, I knew that to design my HTML I'll add style in that file or edit in CSS.
In Laravel, I don't know how to edit the display without bootstrap
can you give me the recommendation to edit that hole the blade in Laravel

Comment: Use flexbox instead

Comment: If i understand you right6 you will display all your studentNames in one column in stack? right?

Comment: yes, something like that, I'll add edit what I want

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right6 you will display all your studentNames in one column in stack? right?
then you have on put the  tag inside the loop.

```php
@foreach($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: in my code, I did that, but there are if-else functions before that.
Do I have to erase the function?

Comment: @user6346 i dont paste the if condition. my code example have only to show you if you put tr inside a loop then every student get his own row.

Comment: so at this point, I was editing my code, erasing the if-else condition, and testing it in the browser in nothing changed Sir